# Retrofit 2 and GSON java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field map contained null value for key

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, gson

I'm facing the following error each time I do a server request since I **migrated from retrofit 1.9 to 2.0**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field map contained null 
value for key 'installments'.
```

The method I call gets a Map with all the parameters like the below code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/method")
Call<Response<Payment>> pay(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
```

but seems that whenever we have one of the entries with a NULL value then it throws an exception and don't even execute the request.

we are also using **Dagger 2**. this is how the GSON is created with a **Converter.Factory**:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Converter.Factory provideGsonConverterFactory() {

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();
       return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
    }
```

**Before migrating to Retrofit 2.0 we didn't have this issue, which is odd.**

*Indeed, Jackson has a property which would do it:*

```
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationConfig
.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
```

Comment: Who throws this error, gson or retrofit/okhhtp?

Comment: at the beginning I thought it was GSON however, later I found out that it was Retrofit. check the line 208 https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/ParameterHandler.java

Comment: BTW, I'm still interested in knowing how to do this.

Comment: That is weird. You should open a bug report on that if you want that fixed (and if they'll agree that it should be fixed) and then you have two options: (1) Go over the map before sending it and removing null key/value entries. (2) Convert the map to json before sending it to retrofit using gson (so that your `pay` method will accept a string instead of map)

Comment: I cannot see this as a proper bug due to they are checking for it. What I could suggest is to have more information about the @FieldMap if so. And you are right, I already gone for the option (1), I couldn't see other way to be sure about no NULL entries before calling.

Comment: It's not a bug, but what you're describing isn't an intuitive behavior and so at least they can explain why it's the way it is, and how one can overcome this limit (you sometimes do want to send null values).

Comment: Agree, even sometimes you are not aware of sending NULLs, and if it crashes locally in your app you may no have way to know about the crash. we have faced this after migrating to Retrofit 2.0 in a Legacy project.

Comment: Which is why I'd open an issue in their github...

Comment: Seeing the same issue...if you don't have control of the backend, they might send you null values in maps.  Anyone know of a retrofit map typeconverter that would filter out the null values?

Comment: Realized the issue in my case was an outgoing request had a map w/ a value that was null (key was non-null).  This shouldn't be done....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From retrofit2, any map(FiledMap, QueryMap, PartMap) did not accept null key or values. See [Document maps don't allow null anywhere.](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/10ff3d97faadcd6f716447d3376f9f51992e44dd)

Comment: thanks for the link, that is what we were discussing above, there is no documentation.

Comment: Do you mean aside from the documentation that is on `@FieldMap` which explicitly states what you're doing is not allowed there is no documentation?